# Disable and enable reading from touch-screen's serial port

Tags: x11, xorg, serial-port, touch-screen

I have X server configured to work with a touch screen through the **egalax** driver and a serial port.

[xorg.conf]

```
Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier "EETI"
    Driver "egalax"
    Option "Device" "/dev/ttyS3"    
    Option "Parameters" "/home/user/egalaxEETI.cal"
    Option "ScreenNo" "0"
EndSection
```

The device where Linux is running should disable the touch screen capabilities whenever some circunstances occur:

- Is it possible to disable/enable reading from the serial port for a while?
- Or should I control the behavior from the application which is running on the device?

Any other alternative?
Thanks in advance.